# Adding action to programatically created UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Here's my code for ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self addMyButton];
}

-(void)addMyButton {
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];

    webView.tag=55;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(aMethod:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [button setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80, 210, 160, 40);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(close:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [webView addSubview:button];
}

- (IBAction)close:(id)sender {
   // [[self.view viewWithTag:55] removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

And here's ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

}

- (IBAction)close:(id)sender;

@end
```

All very simple, but I keep getting this error:

> -[ViewController aMethod:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7141780
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController aMethod:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7141780'

Very baffling!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add aMethod to your ViewController class.

```
- (void)aMethod:(id)sender
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As simple as it gets, `ViewController` is not implementing `-aMethod:`.

I think you missed a copy-paste and you should change the selector.

```
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

will cause `aMethod:` on `self` to fire on a touch down event on the button.

Since you haven't implemented such method, you get a crash. Not baffling at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
[button addTarget:self  action:@selector(aMethod:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(close:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

your code clearly shows you are adding two target . Remove the first

```
[button addTarget:self  action:@selector(aMethod:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

and use your

```
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender;
```

Your code pasted in question will start working